# HTMLAgilityPack xpath

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I have hit a wall with this one, please could someone help me out?

From the URL below I am looking to get to the inner text of

```
<a href="/borsa/azioni/scheda.html?isin=IT0001233417&lang=en">A2A</a>
```

The `XPath` syntax I am using doesn't return any data:

```
.//table[@class='table_dati']//tbody[@class='constituents']//tr//td[@class='name']//a
```

The URL is
http://www.borsaitaliana.it/borsa/azioni/ftse-mib/lista.html?lang=en&page=1

Thanks in advance,

Grant

Answer (score 2):

How about `//tbody[@class='constituents']//td[@class='name']/a`? This should work pretty well, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath starts with `.`, so it is relative to the context node. But you haven't told us anything about the context. Maybe you want to omit the initial `.` and make it "absolute":

```
//table[@class='table_dati']/tbody[@class='constituents']/tr/td[@class='name']/a
```

I would also change the `//` to `/` wherever you're looking for a direct child (not descendant in general) relationship.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, HTMLAgilityPack doesn't play nice with the tbody tag. I just follow up the table with the tr td to find the right cell, skipping tbody altogether.